# Javascript : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have these code, which stores the php variable to a global javascript variable. All the modules are in same file, but still I get an *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*, at the **rowNum1's** line:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var glo = 0;
    var rowNum = <?php echo $_GET['SN'];?>;
    var newnames = new Array();
    var rowNum1 = "";
    var tempVal = "";
    var destTextarea = "";
    newnames=<?php echo json_encode($userinfoarr); ?>; //This varaible initialisation works fine


    function fetchNext(){
            if (glo++ === 0)
            {
                if(rowNum < newnames.length)
                {   
                    document.getElementById("Txt0").value = rowNum;
                    document.getElementById("Txt1").value = newnames[rowNum];
                    tempVal = newnames[rowNum];
                }
                rowNum++;
            }
            else
            {
                rowNum1=<?php echo json_encode($sln); ?>; //This one throws an Uncaught Syntax error
                if(rowNum1 < newnames.length)
                {   
                    document.getElementById("Txt0").value = rowNum1;
                    document.getElementById("Txt1").value = newnames[rowNum1];
                    tempVal = newnames[rowNum1];
                }
                rowNum1++;  
                console.log("test");
            }
    }
    </script>
```

This is the php code for **$sln**:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Txt0']))
        {
            $sln = $_POST['Txt0'];
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the php code for **$userinfoarr**

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT tweet from tweet");
    $userinfoarr = array();
    while ($row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $userinfo = $row_user["tweet"];
        $push=array_push($userinfoarr, $userinfo);
    }
?>
```

COuld anybody help me out with this, as I am unable here to understand the scenario?
Here is a screenshot of the error inside browser
[image]
[image]

Comment: try with put single quote before this :
 var rowNum = '<?php echo $_GET['SN'];?>';

Comment: is it a js file? ..... seems like you trying to access php variable in js file....!!

Comment: So, what does the generated javascript code look like? There's probably an PHP-error message in there that will help you debug your issue. My guess is, _"Undefined variable"_

Comment: U haven't initialised `$sln` outside the if statement. if that if statement never gets called, then `$sln` is not defined.

Comment: @prakashtank : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Could you please add the rendered html/js?

Comment: @mustangDC - "Uncaught SyntaxError" looks like a JS error, not a PHP error. You need to check the generated JS (show source in the browser).

Comment: use `double quote ` in all php code that you use in javascript

Comment: a similar situation works well , `$userinfoarr` with the same scenario.  @Rafiq, @prakash

Comment: @Rafiq - Why? All PHP-code is inside a code block `<?php ... ?>` and the quoting inside that block has nothing to do with the js.

Comment: @mustangDC is your file extension is html then you can't access php variables. It should be .php. Then only you can access php variables.

Comment: @Naincy: I am really sorry , that is a .php file indeed

Comment: @Rafiq : It is a php file and I have put it inside like this `rowNum1='<?php echo $sln; ?>';`

Answer (score 0):

change your php code as below. assign `$sln` default value

```
<?php
    $sln = ""; //<---- assign default value to $sln
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Txt0']))
        {
            $sln = $_POST['Txt0'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have given `$sln =0` and `$sln = "0"`; but sadly I get the same response

Comment: Can be be for the PHP version or something, because I do it almost all the time with no issues

Comment: Make sure this assignment is before your javascript code

Comment: @mustangDC - This has nothing to do with PHP-versions. Is the above code in the same file, before your JS code?

Comment: If I could post the whole code, that would have been better but my .php file goes like<br>
1. php block
2. another php block
3. Some HTML
4. JS

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

Modify $sln code as

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Txt0']))
        {
            $sln = $_POST['Txt0'];

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var sln='$sln'</script>";

        }
    }
?>
```

and in script

```
 {
       rowNum1 = sln; // 

                if(rowNum1 < newnames.length)
                {   
                    document.getElementById("Txt0").value = rowNum1;
                    document.getElementById("Txt1").value = newnames[rowNum1];
                    tempVal = newnames[rowNum1];
                }
                rowNum1++;  
                console.log("test");
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use single quote for PHP code:

```
var rowNum = '<?php echo $_GET['SN'];?>';
```

Comment: var rowNum = '<?php echo $_GET['SN'];?>';

Comment: Unless that value is numeric, then it's not needed.

Comment: Your saving file as .js it will not accept php value try to save file as .php it will work for both php as well as js script

Comment: @BijeshSamani - Please read the comments under the original question. The file format questions has already been sorted out.